# Phusion Passenger not running as expected on VPS upgraded from Debian 7 to Debian 9

Tags: debian, nginx, passenger

I just upgraded my VPS from Debian 7 to Debian 9, it used to run Nginx + PHP 5 + Phusion Passenger. The Debian 9 I am running is 32 bits and is on a 2GB RAM VPS.

Upgraded all software, MariaDB, PHP, but Phusion Passenger it not getting installed.

Followed the instructions in Phusion Passenger's site to use with Nginx: Added the repo, updated apt, but the pkg libnginx-mod-http-passenger is not installing it's own Nginx. I've read Phusion Passenger has a special Nginx package which includes the module.

The command

```
apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

Returns:

```
libnginx-mod-http-passenger is already the newest version (1:5.3.4-1~stretch1).
```

Shouldn't it replace or upgrade the version of Nginx?

Even though everything shows as installed and on latest version, if I try to enable the module just to be sure regardless of not replacing nginx binaries I get the expected:

```
unknown directive "passenger_root" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf:2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up uninstalling the OS repo provided Nginx.

Downloaded the newest Nginx source code as long with Passenger and compiled them both.